# Subtraction in bash

Tags: bash, date

```
printf "$(( $(date '+%H * 60 + %M') ))\n"
date '+%H * 60 + %M' | bc
date '+%H 60 * %M + p' | dc
```

The above will give the minutes that have passed in the day.

Using any of the above time outputs, how do I subtract it from the total minutes in the day (i.e., 1440) to display the minutes left in the day?

Comment: @BenjaminW: intriguing — we made the exact same changes just a few seconds apart, and both changes were allowed (see the edit history).  Arguably a bug in SO, I suspect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I noticed that, too :)

Comment: At least we agree that the changes were needed :D

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I've created [Two identical sets of changes made 10 seconds apart and both edits allowed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340099/two-identical-sets-of-changes-made-10-seconds-apart-and-both-edits-allowed) on Meta Stack Overflow to record this curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following computes the difference of timestamps in minutes:

```
printf '%d\n' $(( ( $(date -d 'tomorrow 00:00' '+%s') - $(date '+%s') ) / 60 ))
```

Note the use of format string `%d\n`. You shouldn't pass your data in the first argument for `printf`, as the first argument is the *format* string, and `printf` may interpret some sequences as the format specifiers (`%d` as integer specifier, `%s` as string specifier, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Given your three exemplars, what about:

```
printf "$(( 1440 - ( $(date '+%H * 60 + %M') ) ))\n"
date '+1440 - ( %H * 60 + %M )' | bc
date '+1440 %H 60 * %M + - p' | dc
```

You don't quite need all the spaces added, but you do need the added parentheses.

Comment: Very nice one-liners. As short as they can be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
minutesElapsed="$(date '+%H * 60 + %M' | bc)"
minutesDay="1440" 
minutesLeft="$(($minutesDay-$minutesElapsed))"
```

Output:

```
echo "$minutesLeft"
332
```

Short version:

```
echo "$((1440-$(date '+%H * 60 + %M' | bc)))"
```